# Random-generator returns null

Tags: java, random

I´m working on a Java-program in BlueJ, and I´m using a pseudorandom generator to generate a random number between a max number and a minimum number. I don´t get any syntax errors, but when i call the method it says it´s a null. Does anyone have any idea? I have imported the Random-class and it´s called randomizer in the constructor.

```
public void attackEnemy()
{
    int damage = 0;
    int max = 41;
    int min = 20;
    damage = randomizer.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    health = health - damage;
}
```

Comment: is `randomizer` initialized ? If not you need to initialize it `Random randomizer = new Random()`

Comment: How is *randomizer* declared?

Comment: Can you post the code of randomizer ?

Comment: What is the code for this `randomizer` and `nextInt`?

Comment: I'm betting @PermGenError is on to the solution. Almost certainly it doesn't *return* null, but *is* null. Big difference. What does the debugger say?

Answer (score 3):

Did you do this?

```
randomizer = new Random();
```

The only value that can be `null` in the snippet shown is the `randomizer` object. You should instantiate it somewhere else in the class where is being used.

Comment: Yes, in the constructor.

randomizer = new Random();

And I also imported it.

import java.util.Random;

Comment: Oh, I´m sorry, I had two constructors. One for creating players fast without taking any parameters, and I forgot to initialize it in the other one. Case closed, sorry guys, stupid question. Just forgot about the whole constructor thing.

:)

Comment: @JoakimVindenes ok, glad to here that! please don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)

Comment: @JoakimVindenes Shit happens. `:)` Remember `this();` next time, if at all applicable. It might help prevent such mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your `randomizer` like this:-

```
randomizer = new Random(); // Without this, it'll throw a NPE
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to state that randomizer was infact a Random. It also looked like in your original code that you didn't quite complete the calculations. Take a look below:

```
public void attackEnemy(){

int max = 41;
int min = 20;
Random randomizer = new Random();

int damage = min + (max - min) * randomizer.nextInt();
health = health - damage;
}
```

I also think that the reason you're receiving a null output, is because you're not returning anything. So you could also display it as the following:

```
public int attackEnemy(){

int max = 41;
int min = 20;
Random randomizer = new Random();

int damage = min + (max - min) * randomizer.nextInt();
health = health - damage;

return health;
}
```