# How can I check for null at a specific index of a String Array to change its value?

Tags: java, random, arraylist, hashset, compare-and-swap

I am trying to print an array of randomly generated sets of three numbers. Sometimes the sets include a `null` value when they are printed to the console.
Curiously,
it is only and always,
two of the sixty-six randomly produce sets of three digits that contain a `null` value.

1. If I check for `null` with an `if` statement using the `==` operator, then Java interprets it to mean "ignore the value" or "ignore the operation" since the code inside the wiggly brackets is not executed and the `null` values print to my console.
2. If I check for `null` with an `if` statement using the `.contains()` method,
   I get a `NullPointerException`
3. If I check for `null` with an `if` statement using the `.equals()` method,
   then the program may stop upon reaching this check.
   If I rebuild the program and re-run it,
   then Java interprets it to mean "ignore the value" or "ignore the operation" since the code inside the wiggly brackets is not executed and the `null` values print to my console.
4. I cannot use `Array[i].charAt(null)` because the `charAt()` method takes an `int`.
5. I cannot use `numS[index].compareTo(null)` because the `.compareTo()` method takes a `String` for an argument.

In an attempt to figure out the reason behind this,
I used the `Math.Random` method or a `Random rng = new Random();` Object.
This did not change the outcome.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I checked the post [[Check if array is NULL at a Specific Index returns NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881866/check-if-array-is-null-at-a-specific-index-returns-nullpointerexception)], but it did resolve my issue.

I also ***modified my original** **code*** as below per the aforementioned post, to:

```java
 while (randomNum.size() < 66) {
        for (int index = 0; index <= 2; index++) {
            int n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
            String s = Integer.toString(n);

            if (s == null)
                {n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
                s = Integer.toString(n);
                numS[index] = s;}
```

and ***also to:***

```java
int n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
            String s = Integer.toString(n);

            if (s.equals(null))
                {n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
                s = Integer.toString(n);
                numS[index] = s;}
```

*But that **did not resolve my issue** either.*

**Here is my code:**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class TestingTests{ 
public static void main(String[] args) { //main() method.
    obj.uniqueString();
} //end of main() method

void uniqueString() {
    while (randomNum.size() < 66) {
        for (int index = 0; index <= 2; index++) {
            int n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
            numS[index] = Integer.toString(n);

            if (numS[index] == null)
                {n = obj.rng.nextInt(4)+1;
                numS[index] = Integer.toString(n);}
            else if (randomNum.size() == 66)
                {ArrayList randomList = new ArrayList(randomNum);
                System.out.println("This is the size of randomList: " + randomList.size());
                Collections.sort(randomList);
                System.out.println("This is a randomList: " + randomList);
                break;
            }
            else randomNum.add(Arrays.toString(numS));
        }
    }
}

int temp = 0, count = 0;
static TestingTests obj = new TestingTests();
String[] numS = new String[3];
Random rng = new Random();
Set<String> randomNum = new HashSet<>();
ArrayList randomList = new ArrayList(randomNum);

}// end of MyClass
```

Here is an example of the output with the `null` values that I am trying to rid:

```java
This is the size of randomList: 66
This is a randomList: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 1], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 4], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3], [2, 4, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4], [3, 1, null], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3], [3, 4, 4], [3, null, null], [4, 1, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 3, 3], [4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 1], [4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 4]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to use debugging statements in your code

Comment: (numS[index] == null) is always false, not sure how you are getting this error, [maybe Random isnt intanced correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364237/random-generator-returns-null)

Comment: It would also help to describe your [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions) since you seem to be writing quite a lot of tortuous code for very little result. Realize too that you're using the *same array* all the time, constantly overwriting it, which is quite likely to be incorrect.

Comment: There is no way that `Integer.toString(n)` returns `null`, so there's to chance that `s == null` will ever be true. I suggest changing your array type from `String[]` to `int[]` to remove any possibility of nulls in arrays. Then render the arrays to strings at the latest point you can.

Comment: your nulls are basically the first 2 passes you do on the for since `numS` is instatiated with 3 empty spaces so at the start `numS = {null,null,null}` after your first passing of the for loop ( the index 0) you get your first number so it goes `numS = {1,null,null}`  and this gets hadded to the `randomNum` set and then the 2nd pass ( the index 1) 
numS will be `numS = {1,2,null}`  and  randomNum will now have `randomNum = { [1,null,null],[1,2,null]}` this is why you only get 2 entries with nulls on the `randomNum` set

Comment: @DanielHernández, yes my `rng`  is initialized outside of the `main` method.

Comment: @Anon, I believe that you're correct. Wow, I can't believe that I didn't see this. I should move the `randomNum.add(Arrays.toString(numS));` outside of the `for` loop so that it doesn't add `numS[]` to `randumNum` until it has been iterated over three times and it doesn't contain any `null` spaces. I am embarrassed , thank you.

Comment: @g00se I have a few months of coding, and I am not familiar with the debugging tools in an IDE yet. My goals are stated at the beginning of my post, "I am trying to print an array of randomly generated sets of three numbers. ".

Comment: I've been programming Java more or less since it was invented and I can't remember having used a debugger more than twice and probably even then to debug into someone else's code. For quick and dirty, you can just put in a sysout but a better solution is to put in proper logging that can be turned off/up and down as you need it

Answer (score 0):

```
void uniqueString() {
    while (randomNum.size() < 64) {
        String[] numS = new String[3];
        for (int index = 0; index < numS.length; index++) {
            int n = obj.rng.nextInt(4) + 1;
            numS[index] = Integer.toString(n);
        }
        randomNum.add(Arrays.toString(numS));
    }
    ArrayList<String> randomList = new ArrayList<>(randomNum);
    System.out.println("This is the size of randomList: " + randomList.size());
    Collections.sort(randomList);
    System.out.println("This is a randomList: " + randomList);
}
```

Change it to a max of 64 (V3′​(4)=4^3), in your code it could return 66 because of the null values.

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much for your suggestions. But you solved my problem, without even referring to it, as use @Anon did above. The real issue is the I have `randomNum.add(Arrays.toString(numS));` included in my for loop, so the first iteration of `numS` is passed to `randomNum` with one instance of `int n = obj.rng.nextInt(4) + 1;` and two empty or `null` spaces. I appreciate your super concise code though. I need to refactor my code and make it as clean.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `null` is a keyword specific to reference types and not for primitive types. So a small Java function to check if a string array is null at a particular index, could go something like this:

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"Stack", null, "Overflow"};
    System.out.println(isNull(arr, 1));
  }
  
  public static boolean isNull(String[] arr, int index) {
    arr[index] == null ? return true : return false;
    }
  }
}
```

And as you can see in this simplified (maybe super-simplified!) example, the output will be

`true`

So hope this answer helps! Thanks! Please correct me if I didn't exactly get you.

Comment: `if (expr) { return true; } else { return false; }` can/should be replaced by `return expr;` (seen this, written this very often lately¹) || `index` is undefined inside `isNull` || (¹ is this generated by AI?)

Comment: You can do the same thing doing `return (arr[index] == null)`, your method parameters are wrong, args in main and isNull are swapped.

Comment: @DanielHernández, thanks for pointing it out, I have edited this. Yeah, i just might have over wrote the code.

Comment: You just change it for the ternary operator. Its the same as doing (like @user16320675 said) `if (expr) { return true; } else { return false; }` but in one line.

Comment: @DanielHernández even simpler: `return arr[index] == null;` (brackets are not needed). Or even better, delete this method entirely and replace with `arr[i] == null` (preferred).

Comment: This is well-intentioned code, but it would add too many lines to my code. I appreciate all your suggestions though.

Comment: @Bohemian, throw a _Scanner.close_ in there for good measure.  Lol!

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am trying to print an Array of randomly generated sets of three numbers, and sometimes the sets include a `null` value ..."*

There are a few inconsistencies with your code.

Consider the following.

```
iteration 1, index= 0, n= 2, numS= [2, null, null], randomNum= [[2, null, null]]
iteration 1, index= 1, n= 4, numS= [2, 4, null], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, null, null]]
iteration 1, index= 2, n= 1, numS= [2, 4, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 2, index= 0, n= 3, numS= [3, 4, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 2, index= 1, n= 3, numS= [3, 3, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 2, index= 2, n= 1, numS= [3, 3, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 3, index= 0, n= 3, numS= [3, 3, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 3, index= 1, n= 4, numS= [3, 4, 1], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 1], [2, null, null]]
iteration 3, index= 2, n= 2, numS= [3, 4, 2], randomNum= [[2, 4, null], [2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2], [2, null, null]]
...
```

> *"I am trying to print an array of randomly generated sets of three numbers. ..."*

You can use the following example.

```java
List<Set<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> set;
Random random = new Random();
for (int count = 1; count <= 66; count++) {
    set = new HashSet<>();
    do {
        set.add(random.nextInt(1, 5));
    } while (set.size() != 3);
    list.add(set);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This is such beautiful and concise code. I realized the issue when I first read your graphic description of the inconsistencies on the iterations over `numS`, and then I read user @Anon's comment. Thank you so much. User @Daniel Hernández also shows it on his code, although he doesn't point it out. I am learning something new with your code; you are declaring a List of Sets here, `List<Set<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();`, and it never occurred to me to do that. Amazing. I'll refactor my code now.

Comment: @Eleazar,  thanks, glad it helped.  My recommendation here, to avoid a similar mistake, would be to start your design using local variables, and only increase their scope as needed.

Comment: Thanks again. I started using this coding philosophy yesterday after watching "How Nasa writes space-proof code" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWYhtksrmhE, so I am improving. In my refactored code, I moved all declarations and Initializations inside my `void uniqueString()` method.  By the way, I couldn't use `random.nextInt(1, 5)`, so I used`rng.nextInt(4) + 1);` instead.

Comment: This is actually quite different to your original output, and to that of @Daniel Hernández, in that it supplies groups of three with no repetition. Yours allowed, say `[ 3, 3, 4]` but it's not clear quite what your requirement is

Comment: @g00se, the reason I did that is because they had mentioned, _"... sets of three numbers ..."_.

Comment: Oh yes. But of course, that phrase might have been used in the loose sense of just "three numbers chosen from 1, 2, 3, 4"

Comment: @g00se, I guess ask them specifically, they may not realize it's non-repeating.